# Schedule a Task in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cron, redis, schedule

I need to schedule tasks at specific times using Node.js.  I've looked at cron and node-schedule and node-schedule looks like a good fit for what I want.  The problem is, when the task is ready to be executed, using node-schedule it can't give me a reference to the task that needs to be fired.  Basically, I need to parse in some sort of identifier and get that identifier back somehow.  Here is the example schedule code:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
    console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

But what I want is:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, taskid, function(taskid){
    console.log('Got task '+taskid+' to do');
});
```

Anyone got an idea?
OR should I use Node Agenda (https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda).  I am currently using redis to store all of the task data and I wasn't planning on installing mongo which agenda requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here :
 1) First , node-schedule is cron-like library but not cron itself and using this you cannot execute a task at intervals (please read wiki for more information). 
2) If your requirement is that for a time specific job scheduling you can take a look at this test case which shows that a job can be given a name along with some handlers :
https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule/blob/master/test/job-test.js

You can later on use this job-name as a reference to perform further operations.

Hope that Helps!